# Ubuntu 20.04 - missing icon images for some applications

Tags: upgrade, icons, 20.04, desktop-icons

### Environment

Ubuntu 20.04

### Problem

I am missing some icon images after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.
*Example 1*: In this case I get a blank space
[image: wrong kolour paint]

*Example 2*: Here I get a generic image
[image]

They should look like:

[image]
[image]

### Question

How can I recover these images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop files are here: `/usr/share/applications` for software installed for all users, and `$HOME/.local/share/applications` and the corresponding icons here: `/usr/share/icons` and here `$prefix/share/icons/`